# Google Cloud Speech to Text NodeJs that from google official document does not work on Google Compute Engine Linux Server

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api, sox, google-speech-to-text-api

I want to develop the speech-to-text conversion of streaming input application using google cloud speech API with Nodejs.
So I used the Google sample source and installed the SOX(version 14.4.1)recorder in my Window PC and running the Nodejs application in local is working well.
But when I uploaded my Nodejs applicaion on Google Compute Engine using Linux Server, the audio device of SOX doesn't work.
The error is 【FAIL sox: missing filename】.
How is the audio received from the client side?
Is there any way to solve above error in Linux? [app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsvwG.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFUUC.png)

Comment: SOX is not installed on the remote. Figure out how to install it or find an alternate implementation of Recognizer that does not use SOX

Answer (score 0):

It seems that GCE Linux VMs don't have soundcard support.

To test this, assuming you're running an APT based distribution (Debian or Ubuntu), install alsa-utils with `sudo apt-get install alsa-utils`, and run `sudo aplay -l`.

The second command lists all soundcards and digital audio devices. It should give you a result like:

`aplay: device_list:270: no soundcards found...`

This means that even if you have SoX installed in your Linux GCE VM, you won't be able to use the speech-to-text conversion of streaming input application (for example [this](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize#performing_streaming_speech_recognition_on_an_audio_stream) or [this](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-speech/blob/master/samples/MicrophoneStream.js)).